# AppVeyor - Share Project between users?

Tags: appveyor

I'm very new to appveyor.
We're having a contributor trying to setup CI for us on this repo https://github.com/kenakamu/UCWA2.0-CS/
So he forked https://github.com/lazaromenezes/UCWA2.0-CS/ and created the appveyor project under his account.
He gave upstream contributors permissions on his fork as well as administrator role on project in appveyor (including myself). 
I still can't see the project on my dashboard however and we couldn't find a clear anser in the [documentation](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/).
So the question is **how can one share an appveyor project with somebody else so it appears on his/her dashboard?**
[issue we're using to track progress of CI implementation](https://github.com/kenakamu/UCWA2.0-CS/issues/42)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppVeyor permission model is not directly tied to GitHub one (because AppVeyor supports other version control systems as BitBucket, GitLab, VSTS etc).

To see and manage some project, [user](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#user) should sign in to the [account](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#account) which contains that project. For that account [owner](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#account-owner) (in your case that contributor who is trying to setup CI) or another user with Administrator [role](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#role) should create a [user](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#user). Or if you already registered with AppVeyor as part of another account - a [collaborator](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#collaborator). If you already logged to another account, you need to [switch](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#switching-between-accounts).

Also for GitHub, you can implement [integration](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup/#github-integration) based on team, but this is optional.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know I needed to sign out and sign back in to switch tenant. I kind of was expecting it to work like Azure or other services where you have a "tenant"/"organization" switch under the username.